# Few fields are missing in printSchema() when read from parquet file using PySpark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a parquet file having one column named as "isdeleted" with boolean as the datatype.

When I printSchema(), that "isdeleted" column is not present in the schema. I am not getting whats going on here.

```
scala> val products = sqlContext.read.format("parquet").load("s3a://bucketname/parquet/data/product")
scala> products.printSchema
```

I am missing one column from the below schema generated from above code:

```
root
 |-- student_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- marks: double (nullable = true)
 |-- height: double (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: First off, you should provide some sample data, the second point, the question is not related to scala.

Comment: @AminMal hi, this is the issue faced by any colleague and that's the info i have right now. Maybe I guess he's using old version of spark?